# PHP mysqli - How can i convert my code into a prepared statements code

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

i have tryed a bunch of different examples of how to do prepared statements but it didnt work for me.

i have problems with converting this code into a prepared statements code

```
function get_all_crew() {

            global $db;

            $query = "SELECT * FROM crew WHERE crew_active_state = 1";

            if ($result = $db->query($query)) {
                if ($result->num_rows) {
                   while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
                       $posts[] = $row;
                   }
                   $result->free(); // Frigør hukommlsen

                   return $posts;
                }
            }
        }
```

i tryed this but it didnt work

```
function get_all_crew() {

            global $db;

            $query = "SELECT crew_member_id, crew_member_img, crew_member_name, crew_member_rank, crew_member_fb, crew_member_steam FROM crew WHERE crew_active_state = ?";

            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($db);

                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query)) {
                    echo "SQL statement failed";
                } else {
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $crew_active_state);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

                    if ($result = $db->query($query)) {
                        if ($result->num_rows) {
                           while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
                               $posts[] = $row;
                           }
                           $result->free(); // Frigør hukommlsen

                           return $posts;
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
```

Comment: You are overwriting `$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);` with `$result = $db->query($query)`. Why?

Comment: i just tryed it @Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always do it like this and it works. I never use `fetch_object()` but you're only asking to convert into a parameterized statement, so here it goes:

```
<?php
function get_all_crew(){
    try {
        global $db;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `crew` WHERE `crew_active_state`=?";
        if($stmt = $db->prepare($query)){
            $crew_active_state = 1;
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $crew_active_state); // OR $stmt->bind_param('i', 1);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
        }
        if($db->errno){
            throw new Exception('MySQL error: '.$db->error); // if there is an error, the rest of the code won't be executed.
        }
        while($rows = $result->fetch_object()) {
            $posts[] = $rows;
        }
        unset($stmt);
        return $posts;
    } catch(Exception $e){
        return ['error' => $e->getMessage()]; // just for the sake of returning an array as well.
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: ive tryed the code and i got this error: 'Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_object()'

Comment: Yes, you're right. My bad. I just updated the answer. Try again with the edited code.

Comment: Also, make sure that `$crew_active_state` is available within the function context. I don't see where you set it, but you should make sure it's set somewhere.

Comment: so i need to do 'code'$crew_active_state='1'; if it says that in my table right for when i did that it worked

Comment: If you want the value to be 1, then I'll update the answer again with that value set. Wait for the edit and see.

Comment: thanks it work with the variable $crew_active_state='1' but when i try with only 1 i get this error: Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference

Comment: That makes sense, I also get that sometimes but not as an error, just a warning. You can do `$stmt->bind_param('i', 1);` too and that might work. Any of the two options is okay since you're setting `'i'` which stands for `integer`, therefore SQL will see it as such anyway.